# Finding the length of inscribed 55-gon in a circle of radius 1, using the inscribed 10-gon and 11-gon.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, math-history

Im am studying the book Vanden Cirkel from Ludolph van Ceulen in 1600. In a chapter on side lengths of inscribed $n$-gons. He postulates the following:
[image]

Which roughly translates to:
I foud the side lenght of the inscribed $55$-gon in a circle of radius $1$ trough the inscribed $10$-gon and $11$-gon.

Now I see where why we could use the side lengt of the $11$-gon. We could use that the length of the inscribed $55$-gon. By using the following:

Let $x$ be the side lengt of the inscribed $55$-gon then we find that $x$ satisfies
$$5x-5x^3+x^5=\text{side lenght 11-gon}$$
In particular the smallest positive solution to this equation. But I don't see how we can use the inscribed $10$-gon.

Comment: How did you find derive $5x−5x^3+x^5=side lenght 11-gon$?

Comment: In general we have that. If $x$ is the side lengt of a inscribed $5n$-gon then the side leght of the regular inscribed $n$-gon is given by the smallest positive solution of $5x-5x^3+x^5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(A_1,\ldots A_{10})$ are the vertices of 10-gon, $(B_1,\ldots B_{11})$ are the vertices of 11-gon, and $A_1\equiv B_1$, then $A_3B_3$ is the side of 55-gon.

Comment: Can you refer me the explanation of this theorem?